# UTF8 problems in jsp and javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, utf-8, html-encode

I have jsp page with textbox that contains UTF8 letters. When I pull the value with javascript it becomes into this format: %u05EA%u...
How do I turn it back into a string that I can understand in java?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are getting that in the first place, but you can use this band aid in javascript:

```
unescape('%u05EA'); //"ת"
```

Better to fix the original problem though.

Comment: What could be the original problem?

Comment: @user1240792 hard to say without any code, track the original point where characters first appear as `%u05EA`, for instance, if you can see that already in the browser's view-source of your page, you have already eliminated javascript as the problem and the problem is on server side.